# Cannot create an archive of React Native app

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Kinda strange problem. My Podfile contains this line:

`pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => ['Core', 'RCTImage', 'RCTNetwork', 'RCTText', 'RCTWebSocket']`

and seems like everything works (I can easily run my application), but when I try to create an archive (to upload my application to AppStore) I see the error that my application contains duplicate symbols. Somthing like that:

`ld: 227 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64`

If I remove the libraries that are in my Podfile from *Link binary with libraries* list, I am able to create an archive, but when I run this application, I see another error: it runs but closes immediately showing something like "Native module cannot be null".

Is there something missing in the documentation? Should Pods be integrated some other way?

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when the Cocoapods installs a second React package. First you should open your .workspace file, than navigate to Pods project. In the Pods project you have to delete 'React' from the targets with the '-' sign. At last, clean your project, and you're done.